# Pandas split the string in each line with "-"

Tags: python, pandas, split, row

I have a dataset. Each row in this dataset has vulnerability and explanation. but I just want to take the vulnerability. I want to separate each line from the part where the "-" sign is

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("dosya.csv")
print(df)
```

my dataset

```
Apache 2.x - Memory Leak;
Microsoft Internet Explorer 11 - Crash (PoC) (1)....
Apache 2.0.44 (Linux) - Remote Denial of Service.....
Chindi Server 1.0 - Denial of Service.....
Xeneo Web Server 2.2.9.0 - Denial of Service.....
```

Comment: What do you mean with "separate"? Create two separate columns?

Comment: What is your expected output based on the sample input?

Comment: Microsoft Internet Explorer 11

Comment: I want before the (-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split function and create a new column called vulnerability:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("dosya.csv",names =['error'])

df = (
    df
    .assign(vulnerability = lambda x: x['error'].apply(lambda s: s.split(' - ')[1]))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("dosya.csv", sep="-")
print(df)
```